# How to get all States and Cities of a country using @react-google-maps/api

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps-api

I need to get all states and cities using `@react-google-maps/api`. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatley, the library does not provide direct functionality for fetching a list of all states and cities, however,one example, you can use the library to *auto complete* on a search bar when searching for locations ..there are many other uses though.. i hope this helps